# Converting Timestamps in Python to UNIX Timestamps

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, mongodb

```
from time import time
time() # Gives me 1298046251.375916
```

I need to convert `01/01/2011 01:48:36.157` to a similar timestamp and am rather unfamiliar with Pythons date / time library. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Is there a equivalent `strtotime` feature?

Considering [MongoDB wants a `datetime` object](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.4%2B/faq.html#how-can-i-save-a-datetime-date-instance) it that would also be accepted instead of a unix style timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short anwser:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime ?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Base Class: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:    <built-in method strptime of type object at 0xb70b3520>
Namespace:  Interactive
Docstring:
    string, format -> new datetime parsed from a string (like time.strptime()).
```

[Documentation reference](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

The full parsing would look like:

```
>>> d = datetime.strptime("01/01/2011 01:48:36.157", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

You can convert it to a timestamp:

```
import time
time.mktime(d.timetuple())
```

Comment: I *just* found that sitting on the bottom of the `datetime` page and finished working out the formula. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to my guardian angel that added the full parsing for me :-)